# Implementing a JSON-serializable ORM model

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, serialization, orm

I implemented a [library](https://github.com/HOMEINFO/peeweeplus) which, amongst other things, implements a JSON-serializable ORM model based on the [peewee framework](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee).
Here's the relevant excerpt:

```
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from contextlib import suppress
from timelib import strpdatetime, strpdate, strptime

import peewee


TIME_FIELDS = (peewee.DateTimeField, peewee.DateField, peewee.TimeField)


class NullError(TypeError):
    """Indicates that the respective field
    was set to NULL but must not be NULL.
    """

    pass


class FieldValueError(ValueError):
    """Indicates that the field cannot store data of the provided type."""

    TEMPLATE = (
        '<{field.__class__.__name__} {field.db_column}> at '
        '<{model.__class__.__name__}.{attr}> cannot store {typ}: {value}.')

    def __init__(self, model, attr, field, value):
        """Sets the field and value."""
        super().__init__((model, attr, field, value))
        self.model = model
        self.attr = attr
        self.field = field
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns the respective error message."""
        return self.TEMPLATE.format(
            field=self.field, model=self.model, attr=self.attr,
            typ=type(self.value), value=self.value)

    def to_dict(self):
        """Returns a JSON-ish representation of this error."""
        return {
            'model': self.model.__class__.__name__,
            'attr': self.attr,
            'field': self.field.__class__.__name__,
            'db_column': self.field.db_column,
            'value': str(self.value),
            'type': type(self.value)}


class FieldNotNullError(FieldValueError):
    """Indicates that the field was assigned
    a NULL value which it cannot store.
    """

    TEMPLATE = (
        '<{field.__class__.__name__} {field.db_column}> at '
        '<{model.__class__.__name__}.{attr}> must not be NULL.')

    def __init__(self, model, attr, field):
        """Sets the field."""
        super().__init__(model, attr, field, None)

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns the respective error message."""
        return self.TEMPLATE.format(
            field=self.field, model=self.model, attr=self.attr)


def fields(model):
    """Yields fields of a peewee.Model."""

    for attr in dir(model):
        candidate = getattr(model, attr)

        if isinstance(candidate, peewee.Field):
            yield (attr, candidate)


def field_to_json(field, value):
    """Converts the given field's value into JSON-ish data."""

    if value is not None:
        if isinstance(field, peewee.ForeignKeyField):
            return value._get_pk_value()
        elif isinstance(field, peewee.DecimalField):
            return float(value)
        elif isinstance(field, TIME_FIELDS):
            return value.isoformat()
        elif isinstance(field, peewee.BlobField):
            return b64encode(value)

    return value


def json_to_field(value, field):
    """Converts a JSON-ish value for the provided field."""

    if value is None:
        if not field.null:
            raise NullError()

        return value

    if isinstance(field, peewee.BooleanField):
        if isinstance(value, (bool, int)):
            return bool(value)

        raise ValueError(value)
    elif isinstance(field, peewee.IntegerField):
        return int(value)
    elif isinstance(field, peewee.FloatField):
        return float(value)
    elif isinstance(field, peewee.DecimalField):
        return float(value)
    elif isinstance(field, peewee.DateTimeField):
        return strpdatetime(value)
    elif isinstance(field, peewee.DateField):
        return strpdate(value)
    elif isinstance(field, peewee.TimeField):
        return strptime(value)
    elif isinstance(field, peewee.BlobField):
        return b64decode(value)

    return value


class JSONModel(peewee.Model):
    """A JSON-serializable model."""

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, dictionary):
        """Creates a new record from a JSON-ish dictionary."""
        record = cls()

        for attr, field in fields(cls):
            if isinstance(field, peewee.PrimaryKeyField):
                continue

            try:
                value = json_to_field(dictionary.get(attr), field)
            except NullError:
                raise FieldNotNullError(cls, attr, field) from None
            except (TypeError, ValueError):
                raise FieldValueError(cls, attr, field, value) from None
            else:
                setattr(record, attr, value)

        return record

    def patch(self, dictionary):
        """Modifies the record with the values from a JSON-ish dictionary."""
        cls = self.__class__

        for attr, field in fields(cls):
            if isinstance(field, peewee.PrimaryKeyField):
                continue

            try:
                value = dictionary[attr]
            except KeyError:
                continue

            try:
                value = json_to_field(value, field)
            except NullError:
                raise FieldNotNullError(cls, attr, field) from None
            except (TypeError, ValueError):
                raise FieldValueError(cls, attr, field, value) from None
            else:
                setattr(self, attr, value)

    def to_dict(self, protected=False, omit_null=False):
        """Returns a JSON-ish dictionary with the record's values."""
        dictionary = {}

        for attr, field in fields(self.__class__):
            if protected or not attr.startswith('_'):
                value = getattr(self, attr)

                if value is None and omit_null:
                    continue

                dictionary[attr] = field_to_json(field, value)

        return dictionary
```

I'd like to have feedback on the implementation of the JSON serialization and deserialization as well as the patching.

**Additional information**
In case you wonder, here are the relevant functions of [timelib](https://github.com/HOMEINFO/timelib):

```
from datetime import datetime


DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'
TIME_FORMAT = '%H:%M:%S'
TIME_FORMAT_ALT = '{}.%f'.format(TIME_FORMAT)
DATETIME_BASE = '{}T{}'
DATETIME_FORMAT = DATETIME_BASE.format(DATE_FORMAT, TIME_FORMAT)
DATETIME_FORMAT_ALT = DATETIME_BASE.format(DATE_FORMAT, TIME_FORMAT_ALT)


def strpdatetime(string):
    """Parses the datetime from a string."""

    if string is not None:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(string, DATETIME_FORMAT)
        except ValueError:
            return datetime.strptime(string, DATETIME_FORMAT_ALT)


def strpdate(string):
    """Parses the date from a string."""

    if string is not None:
        return datetime.strptime(string, DATE_FORMAT).date()


def strptime(string):
    """Parses the time from a string."""

    if string is not None:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(string, TIME_FORMAT).time()
        except ValueError:
            return datetime.strptime(string, TIME_FORMAT_ALT).time()
```